# performance drop of omp threaded function when used in larger program

Tags: c++, performance, nested, openmp

consider the following C++ pseudo-code

```
void x1(){
#pragma omp parallel for
  for(int i=0;i<n;++i{
    //do someting
  }
}
void x2(){
#pragma omp parallel for
  for(int i=0;i<n;++i{
    //do someting
  }
}
int main(){
  x1();
  x2();
}
```

I observe that when x1 is called on it's own in a stand-alone program the execution time for x1 is about 30% smaller compared to when being used in a program together with x2 and called sequentially before x2.
Note that when x1 is used in a larger context/program all threads are available to x1 upon call, so no thread is busy with other tasks. However, x1 will be called in a nested context (i.e. x1 will be called from another function) but with the OMP_MAX_ACTIVITY_LEVELS set appropriately, and even then all threads are available to x1.

I am wondering whether I miss something very obvious which explains the 30%.

Any idea?

NB:

compiler: g++

flags: -Ofast -ffast-math -fopenmp -falign-functions=32 -falign-loops=32 -Wconversion -funroll-loops

Comment: This is very hard (impossible?) to give an answer with such a very generic code (not reproducible by the way), especially without information about the compiler, the OpenMP runtime, the OS, and the processor used to run the code. Please provide such information or at least profiling results. Btw, did you tried to force the compiler not to inline the functions. It would at least discard compiler optimizations though it is certainly not that. Something tell me that `// do something` is the culprit.

Comment: Maybe you tested the routine by itself, repeated a couple of times? That means data is in cache. When you use it in a larger context, data is not in cache. Just guessing.

Comment: Hi. The data are so big that in both cases, test and no-test, it is impossible to remain in cache. Of course in all cases, test and no-test, compiler flags are the same, and the differences where obtained on the same cpu ................ so the only real difference is what is happening before and after x1 is called, and how deep the nesting is, but the data which go into x1 and the thread pool are the same. Further, the non-test application may have even more data in total, which may affect the RAM layout, not sure whether that may play a role.